# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' Python..

Tags: python, json

Here's the code:

```
import urllib, json, unicodedata, webbrowser

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnnamespace=0&rnlimit=10&format=json"



response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
while True:
    if data.get("data") == None:
        print "server error, trying again"
        data = json.loads(response.read())
    else:
        break

for a in data["query"]["random"]:
    print a["title"]
    userread = raw_input("Would you like to read this article? y/n")
    if userread.lower() == "y":
        articleid = a["id"]
        articleurl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=" + articleid
        webbrowser.open_new(articleurl)
```

Now, the for loop isn't that important, as I'm running in to this error:

```
  File "randomwiki.py", line 12, in <module>
    data = json.loads(response.read())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

The url is the Wikipedia's random page article API in JSON. I'm not sure what the issue is. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You recieve from the `urllib.read` function a byte object, but `json.loads` recieves string.
If you want, you can use instead the `requests` module:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
```

Or you can, of course, decode the output from the `urllib.read` function.

```
data = json.loads(response.read().decode())
```